# JMock - several invocations with different arguments

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmock

The method I want to test is calling a mock method with different arguments:

```
public void methodToTest(){
   getMock().doSomething(1);
   getMock().doSomething(2);
   getMock().doSomething(3);
}
```

In my unit test I want to know, if methodToTest really is calling those methods with exactly those arguments. This is the code I wrote:

```
@Test
public void myMockTest(){
    oneOf(mock).doSomething(1);
    oneOf(mock).doSomething(2);
    oneOf(mock).doSomething(3);
}
```

At (2) I get an "Unexpected invocation" - as if it couldn't distinguish different arguments. So I've tried that one:

```
exactly(3).of(mock).doSomething(with(Matchers.anyOf(same(1), same(2), same(3))));
```

But this also didn't do what I've expected.

Finally, this one worked:

```
exactly(3).of(mock).doSomething(with(any(Integer.class)));
```

So I know, that my method was called 3 times with **any** Integer number. Is there any way to make sure, it's **exactly** the argument(s) I have passed?

Comment: Well, the posted code works just fine. JMock seems to have problems with casted objects, though.. Solved so far.

Comment: what are the casting problems? Can you give us more detail?

Answer (score 2):

Did you surround the expectations with a checking block?

```
context.checking(new Expectations() {{
  oneOf(mock).doSomething(1);
  oneOf(mock).doSomething(2);
  oneOf(mock).doSomething(3);
}});
```

Also, are you aware the jmock does not enforce sequence unless you do so explicitly?

Comment: I used the correct syntax and JMock is using a default sequence without having to say so. I'm still not sure, what was causing the problems - I'm using a list and adding an element. Asserting equality to the object and the object got by list.get(0) returned false, altough it IS the same object. Overriding equals/hashcode in my object class solved the problem.